# How to concatenate two columns from different tables in select

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two different tables.

table1.price
table2.domain

I need that in the select I can concatenate this value so that when querying the API it brings me as follows

R$ 13.97 - test.com

```
err = m.Database().Table("host").
        Select(""+
            "host.id, "+
            "table1.price as price, "+
            "table2.domain, "+
```

Note: the select includes several other columns, but the concatenation must only be in these specific ones

I'm using GORM, I searched for the doc but didn't find anything about it

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the query (note: syntax may vary depending on your DBMS):

```
err = m.Database().Table("host").
        Select(""+
            "host.id, "+
            "table1.price as price, "+
            "table2.domain, "+
            "table1.price || ' - ' || table2.domain as price_domain, "+
```

(I would suggest reading the section on [Joins](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins), but since your join is not shown here I'll assume it's fine).

Comment: My solution was to use CONCAT, it hadn't been used before because I didn't find anything about it in the gorm documentation, but in the end it was functional. Thanks